# C++: Instalar OpenCV en Dev-Cpp Windows 10

Tags: c++

Estoy hace varios dias tratando de instalar alguna libreria para poder trabajar con imagenes en C++ usando Dev-Cpp y Windows 10, agrego en el Dev-cpp las direcciones donde estan los archivos .h, los archivos .lib y los archivos .dll correspondiente, pero a la hora de compilar el programa siempre me lanza el mismo tipo de error.

En opciones del compilador agregue los siguientes directorios:

en Cabeceras de C++:

`C:\Users\admin\Downloads\opencv\build\include`

en Librerias:

`C:\Users\admin\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib`

en Binarios:

`C:\Users\admin\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin`

Codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main(){
    cv::Mat img;
    img = cv::imread("Goten.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

Errores:

```
Prueba.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
Prueba.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x36): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
Prueba.cpp: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
Prueba.cpp: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Tengo instalado MinGW64,C++11 y la version del compilador es GCC 4.9.2 64 bits

Lei por ahi que puede ser que porque hay que enlazar las librerias, tambien lei algo de cmake pero no entiendo como funciona

-Realize una pregunta similar sobre FreeImage pero resultó que la version no era para el compilador que tengo entonces no sirvio-

**¿Que puedo hacer para solucionar este error?**

Comment: ¿Has probado compilar el programa con MinGW G++?

Comment: En Opciones del compilador la version que me aparece es la que puse en la pregunta pero compila con g++.exe

Comment: Nota, 4.9.2 es una versión muy antigua (desde 2014). Yo recomiendo eliminarlo y instalar una versión actualizada (mingw-w64 ahora ofrece 9.2.0 si no estoy equivocado).

Comment: Ya lo actualize, pero el error sigue

Answer (score 1):

Qué tal, yo había intentado utilizar de la misma manera en Windows, pero debido a que iba a usar Qt y la configuración fue más compleja para realizar en Windows, decidí moverme a Linux, revisando las diferencias, he notado que yo tuve que hacer el llamado de las librerías de esta manera:

```
LIBS+= -L/usr/local/lib/\
-L/usr/local/lib\
-lopencv_highgui\
-lopencv_core\
-lopencv_imgproc\
-lopencv_videoio\
-lopencv_video\
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_imgcodecs
```

Al principio es para indicar la raíz de las librerías (-L/usr/local/lib/) y de ahí está haciendo la llamada a cada una.

Después, para llamar a las matrices sería de esta manera

> ```
> cv::Mat img;
> img = imread((dirección) + "Goten.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
> ```

Creo que tu resultado

> ```
> Prueba.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
> ```

es porque te falta el segundo parámetro, puedes buscar el que te favorezca aquí
[Modos de leer imágenes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80).

Y si quieres mostrar la imagen puedes usar

> ```
> imshow("Título", img);
> ```

Si quieres no necesitar escribir "cv::" o "std::" todo el tiempo puedes agregar

> ```
> using namespace cv;
> using namespace std;
> ```

antes del main().

Espero que te haya ayudado en algo, y si por pura casualidad es la respuesta, cambia el título de la pregunta agregando [RESUELTO].

Comment: Hola, lo primero que pusiste no lo entiendo muy bien ¿Esos comandos los pusistes en el linker o en la llamada al compilador va eso?. Yo ya especifice en Dev-Cpp donde estan los includes tambien donde estan los archivos .DLL y .lib pero me sigue dando los errores, el error: ```undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)```  no es por la falta de 1 parametro es porque no encuentra donde estan definidas las funciones, lo cual nose porque pasa si yo agrego en el Dev-Cpp todos los directorios correspondientes

Comment: Lo primero lo utilicé únicamente en el apartado de librerías, donde tú tienes * *C:\Users\admin\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib* *, puede ser necesario que agregues una especificación para imcodecs

Comment: Ya probe haciendolo con las librerias y no me funciono :(

Comment: Te muestra un error diferente?

Comment: No, exactamente lo mismo